# Accessing Substrings in a PHP array

Tags: php, python

Assume I have a array like this:

```
$check="Ninja Turtles";
$key=array("jack and jil","peter likes pan","Ninja Turtles");
```

I want to find whether the keywords 'Ninja Turtels' in the $check variable exist in the ARRAY and if so I want to know in which INDEX of the ARRAY it exists in. My above code works perfectly fine, but what if my $check variables has some extra words like:

```
$check="Ninja blah bleh Turtles"
```

My code won't work then. I want to ignore the 'blah bleh' words in my string.

I managed to work around it with Python because I have years of experience in python but I am new to php.

## My Code

```
foreach (array_values($key) as $i => $val) {
    $pos = strpos($check, $val);
    if ($pos === false) {
           echo "The string '$chechk' was not found in the ARRAY";
    } else {
            echo "Found '$check' at Postion: '$i'";


       }

  }
```

## My Full Python Code

```
check="Ninja bleh balah Turtles"
key=["jack and jil","peter likes pan","Ninja Turtles"]
for index, name in enumerate(KEY):
     if(name in phrase):
         print("Found", name +" Index is ", index)
         active="Found", name +" Index is ", index
         break
     else:
         newkey=name.split()
         newphrase=check.split()
         num = 2
         l = [i for i in newkey if i in newphrase]
         if len(l) >= num:
             print('Found', name +" "+ "Index is", index)
             active="Found", name +" Index is ", index
             break
```

Comment: It looks like you used `$chechk` when you meant `$check`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar php code is:

```
$check = "Ninja bleh balah Turtles";
$key = ["jack and jil", "peter likes pan", "Ninja Turtles"];

foreach($key as $index => $name) {
    if ($name === $check) {
        echo "Found $name Index is $index";
        return;
    } else {
        $newKey = explode(' ', $name);
        $newPhase = explode(' ', $check);
        $num = 2;
        $l = array_filter($newKey, function ($nkey) use ($newPhase) {
            return in_array($nkey, $newPhase);
        });
        if (count($l) >= $num) {
            echo "Found $name Index is $index";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple, and perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help you get started...
https://iconoun.com/demo/temp_elo.php

```html
<?php // demo/temp_elo.php
/**
 * Working with substrings
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267396/accessing-substrings-in-a-php-array
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';


$target = "Ninja blah Turtles";
$source = [ "jack and jil", "peter likes pan", "Ninja Turtles" ];

// SEPARATE THE TARGET INTO ITS SUBSTRINGS
$targets = explode(' ', $target);

// TEST EACH OF THE SOURCE STRINGS
foreach ($source as $string)
{
    echo PHP_EOL . $string;
    foreach ($targets as $tgt)
    {
        if (stripos($string, $tgt) !== FALSE)
        {
            echo " CONTAINS $tgt";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of matching check with array  I do it the other way around with preg_match.

```
$check="Ninja blah bleh Turtles";
$key=array("jack and jil","peter likes pan","Ninja Turtles");

Foreach($key as $k => $val){
    $pattern = "/" . Implode("|", explode(" ",$val)) . "/";
    //Echo $pattern;
    If(preg_match($pattern, $check)) echo $k;
}
```

Output:

```
2 //as in $key[2] is where it matches.
```

https://3v4l.org/duYpU

Explode the "Ninja Turtles" to array and put them back together with `|` in-between (regex or).
Then add `/` to complete the regex pattern.
Check if this pattern matches $check.
If true echo key value.

Edit; while doing the dishes I realized $pattern can be done like this instead.

```
$pattern = "/" . Str_replace(" ", "|", $val) ."/";
```

It just replace space with regex or instead of exploding and imploding. Probably not much performance difference but it's more correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with tis:

```
$check = "Ninja bleh bleh Turtles";
$key = array("jack and jil","peter likes pan","Ninja Turtles");

foreach ($key as $k => $keyValue) {
    foreach (explode(' ', $check) as $valueCheck) {
        if (strstr($keyValue, $valueCheck)) {
            printf('[%s => %s]', $k, $keyValue);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

`[2 => Ninja Turtles]`

But you can use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php)

```
$check = "Ninja bleh bleh Turtles";
$key = array("jack and jil","peter likes pan","Ninja Turtles");

$found = array_filter($key, function($value) use($check) {
    return array_filter(explode(' ', $check), function($valueKey) use($value) {
        return strstr($value, $valueKey);
    });
});

print_r($found);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Ninja Turtles
)
```

Or use [preg_grep()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-grep.php) and reg expressions:

```
$check = "Ninja bleh bleh Turtles";
$key = array("jack and jil","peter likes pan","Ninja Turtles");

$pattern = '/' . str_replace(' ', '|', $check) . '/';
$foundbyRegex = preg_grep($pattern, $key);

print_r($foundbyRegex);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Ninja Turtles
)
```